How can I use TailwindCSS with Expo and React Native? I'm facing issues with expo-router and missing configuration files
I'm new to React Native and I'm working on my first project using Expo. I'm trying to set up TailwindCSS in the project, but I'm running into some difficulties. Specifically, I’m seeing errors related to expo-router, and I’m not sure how to integrate TailwindCSS properly. Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Steps I’ve Taken:
Creating the Expo Project: I initialized a new Expo project using the following command:

npx create-expo-app my-app
cd my-app
Installing TailwindCSS: I tried to set up TailwindCSS by running:
npx tailwindcss init
This generated a tailwind.config.js file, but no babel.config.js file was created.
Customizing Expo Configuration: I tried running npx expo customize to customize the configuration, but I’m still facing errors. The log shows the following:
Android Bundled 148ms node_modules\expo-router\entry.js (1 module)
(NOBRIDGE) LOG  Bridgeless mode is enabled

Specific Issues:
Missing babel.config.js: When I ran npx tailwindcss init, it only created tailwind.config.js but no babel.config.js file. I’m unsure if I need to manually add the babel.config.js for the TailwindCSS setup or if it's missing for some other reason.

Expo and TailwindCSS Compatibility: I believe there might be an issue with TailwindCSS working in the Expo environment. I'm not sure how to integrate TailwindCSS properly in a React Native project that uses Expo. When I try to use Tailwind classes, the styles don’t seem to apply correctly.

Expo Router and Bridgeless Mode: I’m seeing the message "Bridgeless mode is enabled" in the logs. I’m not sure what that means or if it's related to the errors I’m seeing in the app. How can I resolve this issue?

What I’m Trying to Achieve:
Use TailwindCSS for styling in my Expo React Native project.
Resolve the errors related to expo-router and Bridgeless mode.
Ensure everything works smoothly without missing configuration files.

Questions:
Do I need to manually create a babel.config.js file for TailwindCSS to work?
How can I properly integrate TailwindCSS with Expo in a React Native project?
What does the "Bridgeless mode is enabled" message mean, and how can I disable it if it’s causing issues?
Is there a proper guide for setting up TailwindCSS with Expo and React Native?

Thank you in advance for any help!
What I’m Trying to Achieve:
Use TailwindCSS for styling in my Expo React Native project.
Resolve the errors related to expo-router and Bridgeless mode.
Ensure everything works smoothly without missing configuration files.

